# How to get date from TextView to DatePicker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a textView and I want to get date from textView to datePicker. The date pattern in textView is dd/mm/yy.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any date and time picker library. Using https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker library you can achieve.

Updated:

```
String date = tv.getText().toString(); // get text from the textview

String[] sep = date.split("/"); // split the text by '/'

int date = Integer.parseInt(sep[0]); // this will contain date
int month = Integer.parseInt(sep[1]); // this will contain month
int year = Integer.parseInt(sep[2]); // this will contain year
```

Comment: how to get date from string format dd/mm/yy to int = date, int = month, int =year for get into datePicker

Comment: String date = tv.getText().toString(); // get text from the textview

String[] sep = date.split("/"); // split the text by '/'

int date = Integer.parseInt(sep[0]); // this will contain date
int month = Integer.parseInt(sep[1]); // this will contain month
int year = Integer.parseInt(sep[2]); // this will contain year

Answer (score 0):

```
    int year, month, day;
    int yearr, motTh, dayofmonth;
    String newDate="";
    ImageView img_startDate;//initialize
    year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    TextView tv_startDate;//initialize


img_startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ReportsActivity.this,
                        dateListener, year, month, day);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                datePickerDialog.show();

            }
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener =
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                            now.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                            yearr = datePicker.getYear();
                            motTh = datePicker.getMonth();
                            dayofmonth = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();

                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            newDate = simpleDateFormat.format(now.getTime());//newDate is string

                            tv_startDate.setText(String.valueOf(newDate));

                        }
                    };
        });
tv_startDate.getText().toString()// get value from text view to datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 void setDateToPicker(String d)
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //use Calender instance for getting the text date.
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); 
            try
            {
                Date date = dateFormat.parse(d); //parse your string date into a date object
                calendar.setTime(date); //set your time into the Calender object
            } catch (ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                        {
                //call back when a date is selected by user
                        }
                    }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); //set the day, month and year from the calender object which have the date set.
            picker.show();

    }
```